# Why I can not connect to my SSAS cube via XML/A in SSMS?

Tags: ssas, ssms, xmla

I have a question on my configuration when connect to SSAS with SSMS. Here comes my action:

1. Follow the official tutorial(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492140.aspx) to config my SQL Server 2008 R2 and IIS 7.5 on Windows 2008 R2.
2. Follow another tutorial to create rational table schema and insert sample data in SQL Server.
3. Use SQL Server BI Dev-Studio to create all cube related things and the deploy it into local server.

The issue is：

- Everything is fine when I connect to SSAS via SSMS with Server name as ".";
- But when I connect to SSAS via SSMS with Server name as '`http://localhost/OLAP/msmdpump.dll`', I can not see any cube related information;

Anything wrong? How can I debug this kind of issue? Is this issue related with the user role and privileges?

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial you are following explain how to expose a cube over HTTP using a web browser to access it. Use internet explorer (or your favorite browser) with the URL `http://localhost/OLAP/msmdpump.dll`.

If you wish to connect with SSMS, use `localhost` as the server name (or `.`).

Comment: Thanks your answer, Dominic. But when I access http://localhost/OLAP/msmdpump.dll via internet explorer I encountered HTTP 500. :(

Comment: Getting 500 is normal because you don't supply a normal XMLA request. Don't worry getting 500 at least means there is such url and everything is deployed properly. That's how I test if everything works here ;) Otherwise you get 404 if not deployed or 403 if security is broken.  Now try sending an XMLA request to that URL and it will work. If you don't want to go so technical about it you can use that URL in Excel to connect to the database